# Segmentation fault w/ pointer to pointer in different struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a priority queue linked list, but keep running into segmentation fault.

My structure definitions are below

```
typedef struct node {
  char *new_element;
  struct node *next;
  int priority;
} Qnode;

typedef struct {
    Qnode *top;
    Qnode *tail;
    int size;
} Priority_queue;

int main() {
    Priority_queue q;
    init(&q);
    enqueue(&q, "hi", 1);
    return 0;
}

void init(Priority_queue *const q) {
    q->top = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
    q->size = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

And my enqueue method where the error is caused below

```
void enqueue(Priority_queue *const q, const char new_element[], int priority) {

    /*......*/

    Qnode *newNode = (Qnode*) malloc(sizeof(Qnode));
    q->tail->next = newNode; /*causes segmentation fault*/
    q->tail = newNode; /*doesn't cause segmentation fault*/


   /*.......*/
}
```

I'm guessing I'm not dynamically allocating my memory correctly, but the way my function is written, I'm pointing from one struct to the next so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please use a debugger. What is `q->tail`? What happens with the *first* node that you add to the queue?

Comment: `q->tail->next = newNode;`: Here `Priority_queue q;` you allocated the 1st node, here `Qnode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Qnode));` you allocated the 3rd node. Where and when is the 2nd allocated?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `q->tail` is initialised to `NULL` and you want to access `q->tail->next`..... That's the problem! You can change the value of `q->tail` first before looking at `q->tail->next`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `init()` initializes `q->tail` with NULL. And you are trying to do `q->tail->next = newNode`. In case of first node it will essentially means `NULL->next = newNode`. This is the reason of segmentation fault.

Your `enqueue()` should be like :

```
void enqueue(Priority_queue *const q, const char new_element[], int priority) {

    /*......*/

    Qnode *newNode = (Qnode*) malloc(sizeof(Qnode));
    if (q->tail) {                /*Do this, only When first node is already allocated*/
        q->tail->next = newNode; 
    }
    q->tail = newNode; 

    /*.......*/

}
```